# Add multiple WPF windows as page to one document

Tags: c#, wpf

I`m trying to print some mark sheets. I created a WPF window and print whole window in this way:

```
PrintDialog pd = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
if (pd.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    pd.PrintVisual(this.Content as Visual, "Report");
}
```

Then I want to add more mark sheet in on document: insert each student marks in that window, add it to a page.
And then print a single file in this way:

```
PrintDialog pd = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();

FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument();
document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new System.Windows.Size(pd.PrintableAreaWidth, pd.PrintableAreaHeight);

FixedPage page1 = new FixedPage();
page1.Width = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
page1.Height = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;
page1.Children.Add(this);

PageContent page1Content = new PageContent();
((IAddChild)page1Content).AddChild(page1);
document.Pages.Add(page1Content);

FixedPage page2 = new FixedPage();
page2.Width = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
page2.Height = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;
page2.Children.Add(this);

PageContent page2Content = new PageContent();
((IAddChild)page2Content).AddChild(page2);
document.Pages.Add(page2Content);

if (pd.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    pd.PrintDocument(document.DocumentPaginator, "My first document");
}
```

But the problem is when I add Window (this) to pages as element:

```
page1.Children.Add(this);
```

I have `Window must be the root of the tree.Cannot add Window as a child of Visual. Source=< Cannot evaluate the exception source>` error.